# How to create a new wordpress post with tags and meta data via REST API?

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using the following code to automaticly create posts:

```
# coding: utf-8
import base64
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint


def main():
    # Init
    url = "http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
    username = "admin"
    password = "password"
    credentials = "{}:{}".format(username, password)
    token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())

    # Header
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36",
        "Authorization": "Basic {}".format(token.decode("utf-8")),
        "content-type": "application/json",
    }

    # Post info
    post = {
        "title": "This is a REST API test",
        "content": "This is a REST API <h1>test</h1>",
        "status": "publish",
        "categories":['2'],
        "tags":[],
        "meta":[]
    }

    # Post
    r = requests.post(
        url,
        headers=headers,
        json=post,
    )

    # Print
    pprint(r.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried couple of ways to add the metadata:

```
"meta":[
    {
        'key': 'Color',
        'value':  'Green'
    }, 
    {
        'key': 'Size',
        'value':  'S'
    }
]
```

And

```
"meta":[{
        'Color': 'Green',
        'Size':  'S'
}]
```

none of those methods seem to work, and the "Custom Fields" section in the edit post remains empty while the result that I'm looking for is to see data there

[image]

What am I doeing wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you seen this yet? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/380513/add-post-meta-fields-when-creating-a-post-using-wordpress-rest-api

Comment: I have seen this. How do I do that with python?

Comment: You don't. The reason why your code doesn't work is because on PHP's side (WordPress) you need to make your custom fields available in the REST API first (as stated on [cvl01's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/384930/135534)). Do that and your REST API requests should work as expected.